# Can't change xaxis in highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I wan't to create a heatmap for different days and months, but i run into a problem that xAxis doesn't change when i add aditional element in array it can have only 10 elements but i need 12.
The same problem with yAxis that is only 5 elements, but i need to add 7 in total.
After adding another element to X or Y axis - nothing happening.

JSFiddle included - `https://jsfiddle.net/nw6ux40e/`

JS below.

````
    var series = point.series,
        isY = dimension === 'y',
        axis = series[isY ? 'yAxis' : 'xAxis'];
    return axis.categories[point[isY ? 'y' : 'x']];
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'heatmap',
        marginTop: 40,
        marginBottom: 80,
        plotBorderWidth: 1
    },


    title: {
        text: 'Sales per employee per weekday'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Alexander', 'Marie', 'Maximilian', 'Sophia', 'Lukas', 'Maria', 'Leon', 'Anna', 'Tim', 'Laura', 'Michi']
    },

    yAxis: {
        categories: ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six'],
        title: null,
        reversed: true
    },

    accessibility: {
        point: {
            descriptionFormatter: function (point) {
                var ix = point.index + 1,
                    xName = getPointCategoryName(point, 'x'),
                    yName = getPointCategoryName(point, 'y'),
                    val = point.value;
                return ix + '. ' + xName + ' sales ' + yName + ', ' + val + '.';
            }
        }
    },

    colorAxis: {
        min: 0,
        minColor: '#FFFFFF',
        maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
    },

    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        layout: 'vertical',
        margin: 0,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        symbolHeight: 280
    },

    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + getPointCategoryName(this.point, 'x') + '</b> sold <br><b>' +
                this.point.value + '</b> items on <br><b>' + getPointCategoryName(this.point, 'y') + '</b>';
        }
    },

series: [{
        name: 'Sales per employee',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [[0, 0, 10], [0, 1, 19], [0, 2, 8], [0, 3, 24], [0, 4, 67], [1, 0, 92], [1, 1, 58], [1, 2, 78], [1, 3, 117], [1, 4, 48], [2, 0, 35], [2, 1, 15], [2, 2, 123], [2, 3, 64], [2, 4, 52], [3, 0, 72], [3, 1, 132], [3, 2, 114], [3, 3, 19], [3, 4, 16], [4, 0, 38], [4, 1, 5], [4, 2, 8], [4, 3, 117], [4, 4, 115], [5, 0, 88], [5, 1, 32], [5, 2, 12], [5, 3, 6], [5, 4, 120], [6, 0, 13], [6, 1, 44], [6, 2, 88], [6, 3, 98], [6, 4, 96], [7, 0, 31], [7, 1, 1], [7, 2, 82], [7, 3, 32], [7, 4, 30], [8, 0, 85], [8, 1, 97], [8, 2, 123], [8, 3, 64], [8, 4, 84], [9, 0, 47], [9, 1, 114], [9, 2, 31], [9, 3, 48], [9, 4, 91]],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: '#000000'
        }
    }], 

    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                yAxis: {
                    labels: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return this.value.charAt(0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    }

}); ```
````

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to use categories you will need to add the new values to the category array.
2. Next, you will need to add wanted points. Notice that array looks like this: [x, y, value], so if you want to increase the yAxis labels you will need to add an additional point for each category.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8pts76bn/

Data example:

```
  [0, 0, 10],
  [0, 1, 19],
  [0, 2, 8],
  [0, 3, 24],
  [0, 4, 67],
  [0, 5, 67],
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.heatmap.data